# Dimensional analysis question...

Tags: calculus

[image][image].

The question (and solution) is given in the pictures seen. My question is how do you get from $x’$ involving $a$ and $b$ to a differential equation for $y’$ involving $y$? The rest is quite straight forward. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try using the scaling parameters then you can cancel coefficients.

Comment: Do we let $y=\frac{\rho}{b}x$?

Comment: No, you let $y = \frac{a}{b}x$ and $t = \frac{\rho}{b}r$ then you insert back in the original equation. Typically one finds a scaling parameter by using an unknown constant and then finding a value that leaves the equation without an explicit set of coefficients.